# Stellar.js glitch when scrolling upwards

Tags: javascript, jquery, parallax

Please have a look at this [website](http://icarus.rgit.in). The problem here is, that while scrolling downwards, the script works perfectly fine, but when scrolling upwards, the classes of the sidebar navigation do not change immediately, but only on scrolling a pixel or so further in the upwad direction.

Please help.

EDIT: I've even tried changing  the default offset in the waypoint js to -1, but doing that resulted in the reverse; now the same problem occurs during downward scroll.

EDIT 2: **SOLVED**: Changed the dimensions and top alignment of the slides which covered the screen. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using Waypoints in order to change the nav menu, the main problem is, the menu are changing when the div are exactly on the top of the page, so you might need to set up the div to trigger on a certain range.

Hopefully waypoints has the `offset` parameter to adjust and dampen this common problem.

```
$('.thing').waypoint({
  offset: 250
});
```

Here's the documentation: http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/#doc-options

Comment: I tried to use this with the selector as `'.slide'` and `'.wrapper'` but none of them seem to work. Don't know what's wrong there. Can you help me figure out which selector to use?